# Form Element Email validation allows invalid email address

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

Today I discovered that `Zend\Form\Element\Email` is not using `Zend\Validator\EmailAddress` for email validation but uses instead the following Regex Validator:

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/'
```

The regex validator allows email addresses such as `example@world-test-de`.

Before filing a bug report I want to check if:

**a)** Why is the EmailAddress validator not used by default? 
**b)** Is the regex pattern buggy?

The above mentioned email address is valid if am using that code:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Email',
    'name' => 'emails',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Notification recipients',
        'description' => 'separate multiple email addresses with comma',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'multiple' => true
    ),
));
```

As soon as I am changing the default email validator, validation works correctly:

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Email',
    'name' => 'emails',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Notification recipients',
        'description' => 'separate multiple email addresses with comma',
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'multiple' => true
    ),
));
**$this->get('emails')->setEmailValidator(new \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress());**
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bug.
`Zend\Form\Element\Email` is a HTML5 input with type `email`, so it is made to fulfll HTML5 specification -> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address

As you can see there is:

> The following JavaScript- and Perl-compatible regular expression is an
>   implementation of the above definition.
>
> /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@a-zA-Z0-9?(?:.a-zA-Z0-9?)*$/

This is exactly the same regex which Zend used to validate emails

Comment: Did you test this example@world-test-de should never validate but does. Obviously the regexp must be wrong at some point. I cannot imagine any valid e-mail address which ommits the TLD

Comment: Local domain name with no TLD is considered as valid email address. Check this page on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples